# HTML input type number, how to start spin at custom value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a number input like so:

```
<input type="number" min="1900" max="2100" name="startYear" />
```

When a user uses the arrows of the input it starts at 1900 (the minimum value). However for this field the most common values will be the current year and next year.

What we would like is that when the user starts using the arrows (up or down) it starts at the current year. However, users should also be able to enter a year by typing it. It is not desirable that the year is already filled in because when the user fills in the year another field is set to the same value (the end year). Therefore the field must initially be empty.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use the js to output the current date or add it manualy through value.

Example: `<input type="number" min="1900" max="2100" value="2014" />`

Comment: But that's not desirable because then it is already filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather set the value using script:

```
$('[name="startYear"]').val(new Date().getFullYear());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t7sj50nz/)**

Comment: That's what I want to do, however setting the value isn't the problem. The thing is that I then need the correct event-handler. I have tried several names in the .on jquery method but to no avail.